# For $C,D \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$: $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D)=0$ if and only if $C$ and $D$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, jacobian, transcendence-degree

The following is a known result due to Carl Gustav Jacob Jacobi (1841):
Let $F$ be any field, $C,D \in F[x,y]$.
**(1)** If $C$ and $D$ are [algebraically dependent over $F$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicallyIndependent.html),
then $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D)=0$.
**(2)** Assume that $F$ is of characteristic zero.
If $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D)=0$, then $C$ and $D$ are algebraically dependent over $F$.

Proofs that I have found on-line are due to [N. Saxena](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/talks/Nov2011-Bonn.pdf) (page 10, with a slightly more general form) and [L. Makar-Limanov](http://www.math.wayne.edu/~lml/lmlnotes.pdf)
(it seems that $\mathbb{C}$ can be replaced by $F$).

In particular, the above result says the following:
Suppose that $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $C,D \in k[x,y]$. 
Then: $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D)=0$ if and only if $C$ and $D$ are algebraically dependent over $k$.

> Is this result still valid if we replace the field of characteristic zero $k$, by the UFD $\mathbb{Z}$? More elaborately, is the following claim true:
>   Suppose that $C,D \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. Then, $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D)=0$ if and only if $C$ and $D$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Edit:** Perhaps there is no meaning for algebraic dependence over a UFD which is not a field? I just meant that there exist $e_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ not all zero, such that $\sum \sum e_{ij} C^iD^j=0$. (This definition looks fine to me;
am I missing something?).

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by $Jac (C,D)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately I do not understand your question (what am I missing?). I have added now a few lines to my question; hopefully, it will be clearer now.

Comment: Could you give me your definition of the Jacobian of two elements?

Comment: Sure. For $C,D \in R[x,y]$, $R$ a commutative ring, $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D):=C_xD_y-C_yD_x$ (the subscripts are partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Thanks. Can you check the following? In $k[x,y]$ for $C = x, D=y$, $Jac(x,y) = 1$, but they are algebraically independent over $k$.

Comment: This does not contradicts my iff claim.